# How to pass the codable JSON array value to another viewcontroller using Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to get `JSON` data using `codable` format. I need to pass the `decoder` value to another view controller after click the Tableview custom cell. I don't know how to do that, I seen some example but its not clear.

My Code below

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
        let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section]
        let item = section.result[indexPath.row]
        print("\(item)")

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondviewcontroller") as! SecondViewController
        vc.dataset = item
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Is this code not working?

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve it in another view controller @mmr118

Comment: `SecondViewController.dataset` should hold the `item`. One issue you might have is if the storyboard is performing the segue and you are performing the segue in your code. This would cause 2 controllers to be created, but only the one created from code will hold the data.

Comment: @mmr118 I am going to use present model. Could you please update your answer here.

Comment: So to clarify you will use a present model from the storyboard, so only in interfacebuilder and not in the code, correct?

Comment: Storyboard I am using but for present transition I am using code, Which is I mentioned above. @mmr118

Answer (score -1):

[image: Cell to ViewController Segue]

This is a segue from a **cell** to a **ViewController** that performs on cell selection, for this you want to do:

```
var selectedItem: Item?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let secondViewController = (segue.destination as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? SecondViewController {
        if let item = selectedItem {
            secondViewController.dataset = selectedItem
        }
    }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Here you are only setting the item variable to the selected one so you can grab it in the prepare func
    // No need to call the segue because the storyboard linkage from cell to controller will be used to call the segue
    let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section]
    selectedItem = section.result[indexPath.row]
}
```

[image: ViewController to ViewController Segue]

This is a segue from a **ViewController** to a **ViewController**, for this you want to:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let secondViewController = (segue.destination as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? SecondViewController {
        if let item = sender as? Item {
            secondViewController.dataset = selectedItem
        }
    }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Here the controller will not automatically perform the segue on selection
    // You call the performSegue function and send the selected item as sender
    // The item will be available in the prepare function
    let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondviewcontroller", sender: section.result[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: this is not I am expecting. I am asking code transition to pass the value and get another viewcontroller. Please check my UITableView, didSelectRowAt inside vc.item. I need to pass it and get it in another view controller.

Comment: You are passing it, but maybe the way other points are set up is making it so you are not on the right viewController. I am not sure. Your first code should work. What I sent were alternatives and WILL do what you want to do.

Comment: Its working by  **print("OUTPUT: \(dataset[0].id)")**